# Install of Asterisk on Ubuntu 15.10 "asterisk start" no such file or directory

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10, asterisk

I'm installing Asterisk 13.6.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 in VirtualBox VM 5.0.10 on a mac mini late 2012 El Capitan host.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/14/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-ubuntu-12-4-lts/)

Everything went smooth until the end of the execution of `./configure && make menuselect && make && make install && make config && make samples` where the following was echoed

> make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../main/modules.link', needed by 'asterisk'.  Stop.
>   Makefile:394: recipe for target 'main' failed
>   make: *** [main] Error 2

I hoped it was nothing an continued with `/etc/init.d/dahdi start` which was successful, but when I went to start asterisk with `/etc/init.d/asterisk start` I received the following error:

> bash: /etc/init.d/asterisk: No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.